# Error: 'null' is null or not an object in IE8 not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I downloaded code to password protect a page. It work OK in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8.  I'm on XP SP3.

It will be accessed by several others so I don't want to have to say 'Doesn't work in IE8 or x or y'

Unlike a previous question it works locally but not from the web. My home page has a link to a file containing the code below. It's at www.bscomputers.co.uk under Glenfest

Is there a fix for this please?  I haven't got access to php etc and it's a low security thing so I want an in the page solution.

the code is as follows:

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', ' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1)
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") { //error on this line
            alert('You Got it Right!');
            window.open('protectpage.html');
            break;
        }
        testV += 1;
        var pass1 =
            prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.', 'Password');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & testV == 3)
        history.go(-1);
    return " ";
}
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>
```

Credit for the code to http://www.javascriptkit.com/ who don't seem to offer any help.

Comment: This has to be the worst protection in history, I hope you are not putting anything serious behind this "authorization"?

Comment: Right click -> show source and everyone will know what the password is

Comment: Right click -> show source and everyone will know both the password and the name of the protected page, and can enter it without the password.

Comment: Oh man, I remember http://www.javascriptkit.com/.  Good 'ol 2002! :-D

Comment: This "page security" is as safe as a simple confirmation box. "Do you have access to the following page? [Yes] [No]" The advantage is that, unlike this code, a confirm box is a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is the problem with IE8, but you are redefining the pass1 variable in each loopthrough.
Try this in IE.

```
function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', ' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1)
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") { //error on this line
            alert('You Got it Right!');
            window.open('protectpage.html');
            break;
        }
        testV += 1;
        pass1 =
            prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.', 'Password');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & testV == 3)
        history.go(-1);
    return " ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajY76/

And as NDM already noticed, this is no protection at all.